# When I try to integrate google maps, I get an error

Tags: api, google-maps, flutter, dart

I try to integrate google maps in my flutter app, but I get the following error:

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 1.17.5.
Because restaurant_app depends on google_maps_flutter >=1.0.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.22.0 <2.0.0, 
version solving failed. pub get failed (1; Because restaurant_app depends on google_maps_flutter >=1.0.0 which 
requires Flutter SDK version >=1.22.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.)

I have inserted the api key into my `AndroidMainfest.xml` file as it was explained in the instructions.
```

Comment: The error says what is wrong... You have flutter version `1.17.5`, and at least version `1.22.0` is needed. Seems that a flutter update should fix that error.

Comment: just run `flutter upgrade` to upgrade your Flutter SDK version to latest version that is compatible with the latest `google_maps_flutter`